# How to disable CNTRL operation in javascript for all versions of IE , Mozilla and Chrome browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, internet-explorer

How to disable CNTRL operation in javascript for all versions of IE , chrome and Mozilla. I have referred many examples available Online, but they all used an alert message to display that CNTRL operation is disabled. But I need an solution without using an alert message to disable CNTRL operation. I have tried a few examples one such javascript example have been enclosed.

Example:-

```
function Disable_Control_C(event){
if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 17){//For IE browser          
       alert('CTRL Key has been Disabled.')
       return false;
}else if(event.ctrlKey){
       alert('CTRL Key has been Disabled..')
       return false;
  }
}
```

Above javascript function has been called as follows.

```
<body onkeydown="return Disable_Control_C(event)">
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function disableControl(e) {
  if (window.event && window.event.keyCode == 17){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  } else if(event.ctrlKey){
    e.preventDefault();
    return false;
  }
}

window.addEventListener('keypress', disableControl);
window.addEventListener('keydown', disableControl);
```

Comment: I need it without alert messages. Alert will stop further processing so I raised the query for the same.

Comment: I need a function without alert messages for disabling CNTRL.

Comment: Okay, I removed the alerts.